Setting up Sqlite with Nextjs for Static site generation inside docker container
I want to setup a directory website with Next.js and Sqlite, with Prisma as the ORM. This app should render the pages (dynamic routes) as static content during build time. And users should be able to add their listing to my site. So this sqlite db should be read and writeable.
I am unable to make this sqlite db connect with my Next.js app during build time. This is my dockerfile:
FROM node:22-alpine AS base

FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat python3 make g++ cmake

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY prisma ./prisma/
RUN npm ci

# Clean up build dependencies
RUN apk del python3 make g++ cmake

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Create data directory with proper permissions in runner stage
RUN mkdir -p /app/data && chown -R 1001:1001 /app/data && chmod 755 /app/data

RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV=production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED=1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs prisma ./prisma/

# Create data directory with proper permissions in runner stage
RUN mkdir -p /app/data && chown -R nextjs:nodejs /app/data && chmod 755 /app/data

# Copy scripts for database operations
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs scripts ./scripts/
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs start.sh ./start.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

# Run the startup script first as root, then switch to nextjs user
CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]

This is my docker compose yml file:
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 3002:3000
    volumes:
      - data:/app/data:rw
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    restart: unless-stopped
volumes:
  data:

This is my npm run prod command:
 "prod": "npx prisma migrate deploy && node server.js"

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Is it static content, or can users add and remove pages while the application is running?  If a user adds a listing, that won't be reflected in the static files that are built into the image.  I'd find it architecturally unusual to need a database or any other running service to generate static assets.

@DavidMaze Users can add their listing to the website while it is running. All the other existing listings should be statically render during build time for SEO purposes.
This is not static assets but for static pages like a blog post page.

That doesn't sound "static" to me; do you expect to recompile your application every time you add new content like this?  Why keep it in a database rather than static HTML files then?

@DavidMaze I am not adding the content, it will be added by end users.
